# Woocommerce Email NEW ACCOUNT template notification FIRST NAME

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need first name in email new account template [woocommerce]

```
my code -> https://pastebin.com/iTfM6Nmz
```

Comment: My code -> https://pastebin.com/iTfM6Nmz

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce doesn't have this functionality built in. The new account email can be sent before an order is placed, which would mean it's before any user information has been captured like first name.

After an order has been placed and you have billing information, then you could pull it in with something like

```
"Hi" . $order->billing_first_name . "Your recent order on"
```

But that would be on order confirmation emails, or anything after account creation.

You could also check out this thread: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-add-customer-name-to-new-customer-admin-order-email/

It's essentially recommending the Follow Up Emails extension to help customize emails. Again it will struggle if the user hasn't added their account information when they register, though, so you might want to look for a way to require filling in WooCommerce user information during registration, assuming it's separate from the purchase flow.